# Is the null check necessary in the following context?

Tags: java, concurrency, lombok

I was reading the [lazy getter example](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy) of the Lombok library, but could not figure out why the null check is applied to `actualValue`, as marked below:

```java
public class GetterLazyExample {
  private final java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference<java.lang.Object> cached = new java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference<java.lang.Object>();
  
  public double[] getCached() {
    java.lang.Object value = this.cached.get();
    if (value == null) {
      synchronized(this.cached) {
        value = this.cached.get();
        if (value == null) {
          final double[] actualValue = expensive(); // the `actualValue can't be null here, right?
          value = actualValue == null ? this.cached : actualValue;  // why null check `actualValue`?
          this.cached.set(value);
        }
      }
    }
    return (double[])(value == this.cached ? null : value);
  }
  
  private double[] expensive() {
    double[] result = new double[1000000]; // `new` won't return null, if not throwing OutOfMemoryError, right? 
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      result[i] = Math.asin(i);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expensive()` implementation is just a demo. The idea is to allow the computation to return null and have it cached by the getter. To differentiate from the uninitialized state, it caches the `AtomicReference` itself as an indication that the computation was done and returned null. It's a hacky approach, but it gets the job done.